# Public posting on fan page with facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I made a script in which automatically put in a fan page on facebook, the script works, but the post is only visible to the user who posted (which is the admin of the fan page), the login'm asking permissions below:

```
$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'manage_pages,publish_stream'));
```

And I'm posting with the following code:

```
$args = array(
 'access_token' => $page_info['access_token'],
 'link' => 'http://www.sitelink.com.br/alguma-coisa',
 'method' => 'post'
);

$facebook->api("/99999999999/feed","post",$args);
```

Does anyone know if the login I have to ask some permission to appear as the most public posts?

I have to configure something else in there in the facebook app developers?

Comment: Have you taken the app live?

Comment: The answer is almost certainly that the app is not visible to the public, assuming you've verified you used the page access token to make the post

Comment: That was it. The app this development as yet. thanks